# Recebendo Nan (not a number) ao ler um arquivo .CSV com numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Usando python 3.6.5

```
import numpy as np

valores = np.genfromtxt("arquivo.csv",delimiter = ";",skip_header = 1)
print(valores)
```

Arquivo.csv:

```
Valores1,Valores2,Valores3
10,20,30
40,50,60
70,80,90
34,54,23
```

Saída:

```
array([nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Não tem a ver com estar passando seu delimitador como `;` e o CSV ter como delimitador `,`?

Comment: @Pedro von Hertwig: Obrigado! Vou testar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já indicaram nos comentários, é apenas o parâmetro do delimitador que está errado. Ao mudar de `";"` para `","` o código funciona:

```
import numpy as np
valores = np.genfromtxt("arquivo.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
print(valores)

# saída:
[[10. 20. 30.]
 [40. 50. 60.]
 [70. 80. 90.]
 [34. 54. 23.]]
```